# Error when storing data to sqlite3 using scrapy

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I m getting the following error on storing data in sqlite3

```
  File "/Users/qasimbutt/PycharmProjects/IntegratedProject/spider_backend/spider_backend/pipelines.py", line 50, in process_item
    self.cursor.execute("insert into raw_tbl values(?,?,?) ",
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I was able to store data perfectly nice and easy in mongodb.But when i shifted to sqlite3 it gives me error. I tried playing around but doesnt works easily.

I am trying to fetch data such as below, which i doubt can be persisted in the sqlite3

```
 ERROR: Error processing {'desc': (('View the profiles of professionals named "Royce" on ',),),
 'title': (('10,800+ "Royce" profiles | LinkedIn',),),
 'url': ('nz.linkedin.com › pub › dir › Royce › '
         'nz-9194-Auckland,-New-Zealand',)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Following is my pipeline.

```
import sqlite3


class SpiderBackendPipeline(object):
   # def process_item(self, item, spider):
   #     return item

   #def process_item(self, item, spider):
   #    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
       # print ("Pipeline",+ item['title'][0])
   #    return item

#Adding new sqlite3 connection
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_connection()
        self.create_tbl()
        pass

    def db_connection(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("rawdata.db")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        print("DB STATUS:DB Connection established")

    def create_tbl(self):
        self.cursor.execute("""
                            drop table if exists raw_tbl
                            """)
        self.cursor.execute("""create table raw_tbl (
                            title TEXT,
                            desc TEXT,
                            url TEXT
                            )""")
        print("DB STATUS:Table created")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
      #  self.storedb(item)
      #  return item
        #print("Pipeline" +item['title'][0])
        #print("DB STATUS: Successfully processed data")
        self.cursor.execute("insert into raw_tbl values(?,?,?) ",
                            (item['title'][0],
                             item['desc'][0],
                             item['url'][0],
                             )
                            )
        print("DB STATUS:Data stored in db")
        self.connection.commit()
        return item

#  def storedb(self):
 #       self.cursor.execute("""insert into raw_tbl values(?,?,?) """,
 #                           (item['title'][0],
 #                            item['desc'][0],
 #                            item['url'][0],
 #                           )
 #                         )
 #       print("DB STATUS:Data stored in db")
 #       self.connection.commit()
        #self.connection.close()
 #       print("DB STATUS:Closing db connection")

    def closedb(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

Appreciate if you could assist me here and help me understand what am i misisng here?
thanks alot

Comment: Side note: In SQL `INSERT` statements always explicitly write down the targeted columns.

Answer (score 1):

Insert statement in SQLite is a bit different. 
You must specify the column names in which you want to add the values.
Like,

```
insert into mytable(col1,col2) values(val1,val2);
```

Hope that helps. Rest seems fine with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get is quite meaningful:

```py
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

This means that you try to bind a parameter with an invalid type, e.g. if you defined `title` as `TEXT` but you try to bind an `int` parameter. As the others already pointed out, explicitly define the targeted columns when using `INSERT` statements, that helps. Next, try to debug on which crawled item it fails exactly, probably you will see that it tries to save something that does not have the type `str`. Alternatively, you can cast every parameter to `str` before trying to save it, but I would rather suggest to debug what is it that you are trying to save exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from html import escape

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.cursor.execute("insert into raw_tbl (col1, col2, col3) values ( escape(item['title']), escape(item['desc']), escape(item['url']) ) )
```